# Can abandoned questions be transferred to new owners for answer acceptance?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer, users, unanswered-questions

I have noticed many questions that have had perfectly good answers for many weeks, but the asker either seems to ignore them, or signed up just to ask one question and then left, never coming back.

Is there a way to pass on ownership of a question, in order to get them off unanswered lists, and answerers get their well-earned reputation?

Comment: http://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2325/3917

Comment: Also, once a question has an upvoted answer, it is off the unanswered list.  We can upvote solid answers, even if the OP never comes back to accept one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.  Answer acceptance is a complete *optional* action.  It is not, and never will be, a requirement.  The rep gain is minimal, anyways; two answer upvotes bypasses it.

Answer (score 2):

The only questions which are at all a problem when inactive are unclear questions – as in, we need the asker to clarify their situation, but they're not responding, for whatever reason. Those we close as "unclear" after a polite delay. (Arguably, even a polite delay isn't necessary, but it's often done anyway.)

Everything else that doesn't yet have an upvoted answer is fine – no answer has yet arrived that is acceptable enough to have a positive score, so it still needs an answer. That's the site working as designed.